# String Interpolation on Jquery Event Handler Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, iteration, string-interpolation

I've searched all over SO and the Internet and can't find a workable solution for this problem. Essentially, I have a JSON .get request that is returning an array of Ruby objects. I'm then iterating over these objects and placing them in li's that are then inserted into the DOM. However, I'm trying to attach an .on click event handler to each li and despite what I try the string won't interpolate the jquery objects and attach the event handler:

```
function getPrevious(data) { 
   var gamesDiv = '' 
 $.get("/games", function(data) { 
data.data.forEach(function(game) { 
gamesDiv += $(`<li class="game" data-id="${game.id}"> ${game.id} ${game.attributes.state} \n </li>`).on("click", function (e) {

  alert("hello")
 }); 
   $("#games").html(gamesDiv) 
 }); 
}
```

the current incarnation doesn't even show in the DOM. On other efforts, I've had it show, but appear only as [object object][object object] without the event handler attached.

I've been trying to get this to work for hours, so if there is any insight anyone could provide I'd be extremely thankful!

Comment: Can you show the `data` you receive from the GET request?

Comment: the first iteration through the data is: game = Object {id: "1", type: "games", attributes: Object}

Comment: and the second is game = Object {id: "2", type: "games", attributes: Object}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't treat a `jQuery` object as a string, this is the main reason why errors are showing in your code since you're trying to concatenate `gameDiv` with a `jQuery` object.

You can simplify this by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in each of the game data, returning the `jQuery` instance representing the list (this also includes registering event handlers and etc).

After transforming the game list into an array of `<li>` `jQuery` instances, then you may replace the contents of the `#games` element with the transformed array.

```
function getPrevious(data) {
  $.get('/games', function(data) {
    var list = data.data.map(function(game) {
      return $(
        `<li class="game" data-id="${game.id}">
        ${game.id} ${game.attributes.state} \n
        </li>`
      ).on('click', function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(game, 0, 4));
      });
    });
    $('#games').html(list);
  });
}
```

```js
// This mocks the $.get function, to provide controlled result
$.get = function(route, callback) {
  return callback({
    data: [
      { id: 1, attributes: { state: 'State 1' } },
      { id: 1, attributes: { state: 'State 2' } },
      { id: 1, attributes: { state: 'State 3' } }
    ]
  });
};
// Do not include the code above in your code base

function getPrevious(data) {
  $.get('/games', function(data) {
    var list = data.data.map(function(game) {
      return $(
        `<li class="game" data-id="${game.id}">
        ${game.id} ${game.attributes.state} \n
        </li>`
      ).on('click', function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(game, 0, 4));
      });
    });
    $('#games').html(list);
  });
}

getPrevious();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul id="games">

</ul>
```

Comment: thanks so much. i'm a little new to jquery and that helped a ton!